# Запятая перед «ещё»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Так ли уж необходима запятая перед придаточным? Вроде Лопатин и Валгина за нее. Но я вместе с героиней как-то спотыкаюсь о вторую запятую. А ну как читатель и вообще растянется?

> – Мне кажется, я проснулась ещё когда ты уходил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, в данном случае применим п. 6 из справочника Д. Э. Розенталя.

> 6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы как раз, только, лишь, исключительно и т. п., то перед ними ставится запятая (вопреки интонации, так как при чтении пауза перед ними не делается): Катя вышла из столовой, как раз когда мы шагнули друг к другу через какие-то чемоданы (Кав.). 
>      http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=129

Answer (score 3):

Хоть застрелись, но две основы (я проснулась + ты уходил) должны быть разъединены. Розенталь первый это нам объяснил, до Валгиной (Лопатин, как экспериментатор, не рассматривается).

[Вопрос № 293012](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20293012)

> Здравствуйте! Нужна ли запятая перед "только" в данном предложении:
>   "Мы ценим настоящее только когда выбираемся из наших грез"?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Да, запятую надо поставить. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят
>   усилительные частицы *как раз, только, лишь, исключительно* и т. п.,
>   то запятая ставится перед ними вопреки интонации.

*Ещё когда* спокойненько попадает в "и т. п.": *как раз когда*.

---

Попутно нашла [интересное](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827520.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B10%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%C2%A7336) (не знала):

> Не ставится запятая и если имеется несколько относительных слов,
>   выступающих в роли однородных членов предложения: *Не знаю  почему и
>   каким образом,  но письмо вдруг исчезло; Позвонят — расспроси  кто и
>   зачем.*

Comment: Справочная служба явно заглянула сюда (п. 6): http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=129

Comment: Ну она же выдумывать не вправе, вот и олд-розенталь. )))

Answer (score 3):

**Мне кажется, я проснулась, ещё когда ты уходил.**

В данном предложении ***еще*** является частицей:

ЕЩЁ III. частица. 2. Употр. для уточнения, подчёркивания какого-л. признака, факта.

Следовательно, по правилу запятая между союзом КОГДА и ***еще*** не ставится: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134  Паузы там тоже нет. Постановка запятой соответствует только **грамматическому принципу.**

**А где-нибудь есть пауза, как без неё**?  После вводного предложения ***мне кажется*** пауза тоже не делается, оно встраивается в общую конструкцию.

Дело в том, что в этом предложении делается **фонетическая перестройка**: оно делится на две фразы, небольшая пауза обозначает перелом интонации. Мы читаем его так: **Мне кажется, я проснУлась // ещё когда ты уходИл.**